# yet again problems with ssh key... but this time on github

Tags: github

So, I have my pubkeys on github.
Somehow from one of my devices I can't push commits..

```
> git pull --tags origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

of course I checked the ssh keys on my github page, thinking that maybe I forgot to put this specific device key in it.
but when I try to add it it tells me the key is already there.

Then I tried to connect through ssh to my github account and of course it works.

```
Hi mosfetti! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

What should I do?
Thanks

(Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

apparently something was rong with origin url..
still don't know why..

solved by adding the origin again

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myuser/myrepo
```